# Lua escape multiline string

Tags: string, lua, escaping

Hello I'm wondering if I can escape the [[ and ]] in a mutli line string

example:

```
s = [[  [[ test ]] ]]
```

and then if I do

```
print(test)
```

I would like the output to be, `[[ test ]]`

is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lua multiline strings don't just use `[[` and `]]`; you can also put as many `=` between the two `[` and `]` (it has to be the same number though):

```lua
local str = [=====[
 ]] This does nothing
 ]=] not enough =
 ]==========] too many =
]=====] -- This closes the string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [=[ [[Hello]] ]=]
print(s)
```

Output
`[[Hello]]`

Seems to work, but I'm just learning this solution as I research to answer this question so I don't know if there are any caveats.